# Unable to output data from ram memory address

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I am trying to build a ram in vhdl and in the below code I am successful in storing data in the ram locations 0000 and 0001. I am not successful in outputting the data from memory locations 0000 and 0001.

The following code is for the ram vhdl.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity ram is
  port (
    clock   : in  std_logic;
    we      : in  std_logic;
    address : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    datain  : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    dataout : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
  );
end entity ram;

architecture RTL of ram is

   type ram_type is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(datain'range);
   signal ram_comp : ram_type;
   signal read_address : std_logic_vector(address'range);

begin

  RamProc: process(clock) is

  begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
      if we = '1' then
         ram_comp(to_integer(unsigned(address))) <= datain;
      end if;
      read_address <= address;
    end if;
  end process RamProc;

  dataout <= ram_comp(to_integer(unsigned(read_address)));

end architecture RTL;
```

The following code is a testbench for the ram vhdl code.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity ram_tb is
end entity;

architecture behave of ram_tb is
component ram
    port(
            clock   : in  std_logic;
            we      : in  std_logic;
            address : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            datain  : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            dataout : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)  
    );
end component;

signal clock, we : std_logic;
signal datain, dataout : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal address : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

constant T : time := 20 ns;

begin
    clock_process : process
        begin
             clock <= '0';
             wait for T/2;
             clock <= '1';
             wait for T/2;
        end process;

    stim_process : process
        begin
            address <= "0000";
            datain <= "00001111";
            we <= '1';
            wait for 20 ns;
        
            address <= "0001";
            datain <= "00001100";
            wait for 20 ns;
        
            we <= '0';
            wait for 20 ns;
        
            address <= "0000";
            wait for 20 ns;
        
            address <= "0001";
            wait for 20 ns;
        
            assert false report "Reached end of test";
            wait;
        end process;
end behave;
```

Simulation of the ram_tb screenshot

[image]

How can I output the data from address 0000 and 0001 on the dataout signal?

I tried the simulation on ModelSim below is the result of the simulation

[image]

the output is working fine. How is this possible?

Comment: It might help if you instantiate ram in ram_tb. It'd be useful to show read_address in the waveform as well.

Comment: Please check the new simulation image

Comment: Your new image makes no difference if the testbench you're using that fails doesn't  instantiate the component being 'tested'.  I noticed this while duplicating  your waveform. [Adding it in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SprEJ.jpg) and miraculously the simulation shows reads work.  Check the testbench in your question before going on about a different simulation environment.

Comment: You'll fihd that all those persistent 'U's in your new simulation environment (that doesn't match the testbench here) are locations in ram that haven't been written to as yet. Note the declaration (`signal ram_comp : ram_type;`) doesn't provide an initial value, so the value is 'U's.

Comment: The problem is with the testbench code its missing the port map declaration this is why it wasn't outputing anything. I will edit in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the testbench code the port map must be added.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity ram_tb is 
end entity;

architecture behave of ram_tb is
component ram
    port(
            clock   : in  std_logic;
            we      : in  std_logic;
            address : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            datain  : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            dataout : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)  
    );
end component;

signal clock, we : std_logic;
signal datain, dataout : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal address : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

constant T : time := 20 ns;

begin
    uut: ram port map(clock, we, address, datain, dataout);

    clock_process : process
        begin
             clock <= '0';
             wait for T/2;
             clock <= '1';
             wait for T/2;
        end process;

    stim_process : process
        begin
            address <= "0000";
            datain <= "00001111";
            we <= '1';
            wait for 20 ns;
    
            address <= "0001";
            datain <= "00001100";
            wait for 20 ns;
    
            we <= '0';
            wait for 20 ns;
    
            address <= "0000";
            wait for 20 ns;
    
            address <= "0001";
            wait for 20 ns;
    
            assert false report "Reached end of test";
            wait;
        end process;
end behave;
```